# Is there a forum software similar to Vanilla or bbPress?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for some forum software that is similar to [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/) and [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) in that there is a 'global topic list' with tags/subforums narrowing down the focus, as opposed to topics being split between subforums by default.

The reason I ask for alternatives is because neither of those forums support PostgresSQL, which my main site already runs just dandy on, and I would like to avoid installing MySQL if at all possible.  The forum can run on either PHP or Python, a Django app would be even nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably just go with Vanilla, if possible. If it has the feature set you require, there isn't much of a problem allowing both databases to coexist.

Comment: I was more worried about memory/CPU footprint.  It's not necessarily a problem now, but I might be migrating off my dedicated server to a VPS soonish, and I'd like all the free RAM I can get.